# Shell Script for logging into a ssh server

Tags: ssh, password, expect

I tried writing a shell script which can do automatic login into a ssh server using password which is mentioned in the script. I have written the following code:

```
set timeout 30
/usr/bin/ssh -p 8484 root@172.31.72.103
expect 
{
   "root@172.31.72.103's password" 
   {
      send "password\r" 
   }
}
```

This code is not running properly, still it is asking for the password. Can somebody please help me in solving this

Comment: Related: [pass password to su/sudo/ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/q/233217/95735)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password

Comment: This [link](https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/) here might also be useful.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I once wrote an `expect` script to log in to a ssh server (like your case) and my script was something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh MyUserName@192.168.20.20
expect "password"
send "MyPassword\r"
interact
```

I think maybe the `interact` is missing in your script.

Comment: this is absolutely working fine for me and i am stuck in this place, the interact provides interactive terminal with prompt, but i am trying to automate further more steps like do `cd` and `ls` and read the contents of the file as well. Is it possible to do after interact? Please reply

Comment: @Hansie you can send an `ls` command after the login. For example after sending password, do an `expect` with the command prompt text (to make sure you are logged in), then `send "ls\r"`. All of these goes before `interact`.

Comment: the question was slightly incorrect and i am sorry after doing ls and read contents, i am able to print the same. But how to get that out of ssh session into a variable to access from local machine. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341234/expect-script-return-value. But output is not working for me. My question posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628465/how-to-change-directory-in-shell-script/51637048?noredirect=1#comment90238913_51637048. I need `file_list` after exit to access from local command prompt

Comment: `send "MyPassword\r"` is not working @saeedn

Comment: this is not working for me on ubuntu

Comment: If you get an `/usr/bin/expect bad interpreter no such file or directory` error, try installing expect with `sudo apt install expect`

Answer (score 35):

You're going about it the wrong way. What you want to do is generate a passwordless ssh-key pair and then (as long as the server supports RSA key authentication) you can get in without having to type a password for all. This is a security risk if your private key is stored somewhere that it could be stolen.

Follow these steps:

1. `mkdir -p ~/.ssh`
2. `cd ~/.ssh`
3. `ssh-keygen -type dsa -i mysshkeys`
4. Press <kbd>Return</kbd> when prompted for passphrase
5. Press <kbd>Return</kbd> a second time to confirm.

There will now be two files in your `~/.ssh` directory, `mysshkey.pub` and `mysshkey`. `mysshkey.pub` is your public key, this one is safe to put on remote servers. `mysshkey` is your private passwordless key, it is *not* safe to put on remote servers (or somewhere someone else could get a copy).

On the server you wish to SSH into:

1. Login to the remote server
2. `mkdir -p ~/.ssh`
3. Copy and paste the contents of `mysshkey.pub` into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
4. Make sure that `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is `chmod`'d to `600`

Now, to put it into action on your local machine you run the following command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mysshkey <remote_server_ip>
```

And you will be logged in without being prompted for a password.

This is a much preferable method of managing automated logins as you don't end up hard-coding your password multiple places that need to be updated if you ever change it.

Comment: I would use RSA keys rather than DSA. But other than that, full agree.

Comment: sometimes you cannot add keys to the remote host, eg network appliances.

Comment: I tried this. ssh is still asking for a password. Do you specifically have to give an IP address? I tried it with both <user>@<domain-name> and just the domain name.

Comment: This command said too many arguments? (for step 3)

Comment: I had to change to ssh-keygen -t dsa and manually enter file location instead.

Comment: @JayBienvenu did you ever get it to work?

Comment: I finally got it to work.  I was using digital ocean, trick is to go to settings in digitalocean found under your profile image upper right, click security, add the ssh key here, then you have to login as root@domainhere.com

Comment: I do prefer this method, but my company does not create home directories on the remote servers, so it's nice to have a script alternative.

Answer (score 22):

On Debian-based distributions, the `sshpass` package provides an easier way of doing what you want. The package is available for many other popular distributions. You need to set it up first:

```
echo 'YourPassword' > passwordFile.txt
chmod 600 passwordFile.txt
```

Then invoke the SSH command from a script like this:

```
sshpass -f /path/to/passwordFile.txt /usr/bin/ssh -p 8484 root@172.31.72.103
```

This provides more flexibility, such as if you're using a different locale or need to change the password, than solutions using `expect`.

Answer (score 9):

you can use this:

```
sshpass -p 'yourpassword'  ssh user@ip
```

Answer (score 8):

First install the sshPass `sudo apt-get install sshpass`

Then create an alias in .bashrc file as

```
alias sshLogin='sshpass -p <your ssh password> ssh username@remote_host'
```

Now reload your changed .bashrc file by `source ~/.bashrc`

You are now done.

Now you can run the ssh using the above created alias `sshLogin` in terminal.

Answer (score 3):

All what you need it to create a hashed key and save it on your PC

Just type

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 # just press Enter till the end
```

then enter

```
ssh-copy-id <user>@<server>
```

then login normally using

```
ssh <user>@<server>
```

Now you don't need a password

> Note: Saving your password in a plain text is dangerous
>
> This method is creating a hashed value of your password using RSA with public key of length 4096 which is very secure.

Comment: This appears to be a repeat of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31075/100397).

Comment: #roaima Yes, but it algo suggests the incredibly useful `ssh-copy-id` command, which nobody else mentioned. I'm upvoting it for that.

Answer (score 2):

As already described in other answers, I also use `sshpass` but I combine it with the `read` command to store my password in an temporary environment variable. This way my password is never written anywhere in clear. Here is the one line command I use:

```
read -s PASS; sshpass -p $PASS ssh <user>@<host adress>
```

After that you have to enter your password (nothing appears on the screen) and then pressing enter will open the connection.

Answer (score 1):

[SSH Passwordless Login Using SSH Keygen in 5 Easy Steps](https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/):

Environment setup:
[image]

**Step 1:** *Authentication SSH-Kegen Keys on – (192.168.0.12)*
First login into server 192.168.0.12 with a user and generate a pair of public keys using following command.

[image]

**Step 2:** *Create .ssh Directory on – 192.168.0.11*
Use SSH from server 192.168.0.12 to connect server 192.168.0.11 to create .ssh directory under it, using following command.

[image]

**Step 3:** *Upload Generated Public Keys to – 192.168.0.11*
Use SSH from server 192.168.0.12 and upload new generated public key (id_rsa.pub) on server 192.168.0.11 under user's `.ssh` directory as a file name authorized_keys.

[image]

**Step 4:** *Set Permissions on – 192.168.0.11*
Due to different SSH versions on servers, we need to set permissions on `.ssh` directory and `authorized_keys` file.

[image]

**Step 5:** *Login from 192.168.0.12 to 192.168.0.11 Server without Password*
From now onwards we can log into 192.168.0.11 as sheena user from server 192.168.0.12 as tecmint user without password.

[image]

Comment: Thanks... this worked for me, except at step 4 I got a dramatic "warning": "UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE! ... .../.ssh/id_rsa' are too open. ... private key will be ignored... bad permissions".  I did `chmod 700 id_rsa` in directory .ssh in the local (client, i.e. 192.168.0.12 in your example) server: problem solved

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this, this may help you:

```
sshpass -p 'password' username@ipaddress
```

if this doesn't work then you'll have to generate keys in the other machine you want to connect with

```
ssh-keygen
```

it will generate private and public keys and ask you for a location, leave at empty it will save the keys in .ssh folder by default
it will ask you for passphrase, you can also leave it empty
the go in .ssh folder and change the public key name to 'authorized_keys'

```
cd .ssh/
mv id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
useradd -d /home/username username
```

this will add user to list
now go to home directory and give permission and restart sshd services

```
chmod 700 /home/username/.ssh
chmod 644 /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown root:root /home/dozee
sudo service sshd restart
```

now you will have to move the private key to the system at that location from where you are going to run the ssh command, then you can connect with

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh -i id_rsa username@ip
```

if even that doesn't work then go in /etc/ssh open sshd_config with vim editor
check if the pubkeyAuthenticatoin is turned to yes or not, if not change it to yes , restart the sshd services  and then try it, it will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

First argument is hostname and second is password.

```
     #!/usr/bin/expect
     set pass [lindex $argv 1]
     set host [lindex $argv 0]
     spawn ssh -t root@$host echo Hello
     expect "*assword: "
     send "$pass\n";
     interact
```

Execution:

```
./script.expect hostname "my!password?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the appropriate option

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password user@remote.server.tld
```

You can also go the other way around and simply forbid using keys.

```
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@remote.server.tld
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely bash answer

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $1 =~ 'password:' ]] && cat || SSH_ASKPASS="$0" DISPLAY=nothing:0 exec setsid "$@"
```

Save it as `pass`, do a `chmod +x pass` and then use it like this:

```
echo mypass | pass ssh user@host ...
```

If its first argument contains `password:` then it passes its input to its output (`cat`) otherwise it launches whatever was presented after setting itself as the `SSH_ASKPASS` program.

When ssh encounters both `SSH_ASKPASS` AND `DISPLAY` set, it will launch the program referred to by `SSH_ASKPASS`, passing it the prompt `user@host's password:`