# Autentification on SSH connection in OneLine

Tags: ssh, shell-script, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell Script for logging into a ssh server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31071/shell-script-for-logging-into-a-ssh-server)

I need to connect via SSH to a remote server, however I must do this with out interactive mode and with out use Public keys and also with out install extra packes like sshpass or expect because it's a unix system based, I was wondering if it's possible using a script or send the pass together the command ssh connection, something like this:

```
$: ssh user@remoteserver \npassword
```

Comment: Or with some library on Java

Comment: Seemingly needless crosspost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283360/open-ssh-connection-in-one-line-command-with-out-public-key

Answer (score 3):

No, it deliberately isn't possible to do this.  You will need to use one of those tools, or a public key without a passphrase.

Comment: That's wrong. The makers of ssh deliberately make it difficult, because it's a bad idea, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do is this way consider using Expect like so:

http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/

Comment: Please provide [some context for links](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) so that the answer is not dependant on an external site.