# Automated SSH Login

Tags: ssh, shell-script, administration, system-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell Script for logging into a ssh server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31071/shell-script-for-logging-into-a-ssh-server)
>   [Autentification on SSH connection in OneLine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/autentification-on-ssh-connection-in-oneline)

How could I make a SSH Login programmatically on a unix server, I don't have rights for generate public keys on the side server or extra-packages like expect. The client is a windows os, so I use putty to do the connections. Is there any way to use putty on my program or any java library for this?

Comment: You could also generate keys somewhere else and `scp` the public one to the server, couldn't you?  (Or does the SSH server not allow using keys?)

Comment: The server neither  not allow using public key or install extra-packages

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Putty, but rather [Kitty](http://kitty.9bis.com/), and there is a setting to save your password under connection -> data -> auto-login password. Putty doesn't seem to have that option.

Answer (score 0):

While you could save your creds with another tool I would talk to your sysadmin and ask for pk auth first. If you are doing something legitimately they will appreciate you bringing this up with them instead of going around the system with saved creds or an autoit script, etc. I would think they would at least point you in the right direction.