# How can I loggin from VM1 to VM2 using script?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am using script to loggin my VM2 from VM1 (Password of the VM2: fifa):

```
for i in {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z} 

do

# $i as a password

ssh root@ipaddress 

read i

echo $i

done
```

bit it doesn't work. It always ask me to enter the password.
How can I make it to enter password automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It's asking you to enter "the password" because of the `read i` statement, which is clobbering your `for` loop variable. I believe the ssh client tries to read from the tty; I'm not aware of a direct way to pass a password to ssh. Alternatives include sshpass and expect. See [SSH login with clear text password as a parameter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38737/ssh-login-with-clear-text-password-as-a-parameter) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/pass-password-to-su-sudo-ssh and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118308/command-line-to-execute-ssh-with-password-authentication