# ssh to remote machine using shell script

Tags: ssh

I want to ssh to remote machine within shell script but remote machine require password. How should i provide password in my script?

I tried below but its not working. Please suggest

```
#!/bin/bash
SSH <hostname>
<password>
```

Comment: Don't. Instead, use a passwordless SSH key with limited permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a ssk-key so you do not have to provide any password. There are plenty of tutorials out there  on how to use them, for example [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) one.

In case you want to use inline password you can try installing `sshpass` and executing:

```
sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh user@host
```

Source: [SSH login with clear text password as a parameter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38737/ssh-login-with-clear-text-password-as-a-parameter)

By the way, if you want to execute a command in the remote machine, you just have to write the remote command between quotation marks:

```
sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh user@host "ls -l"
```