# Opening many tunnels typing the password only once (all accounts in gateways have the same pass)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh

I want to open many tunnels at once, they all have the same long password.

With `-f`, i.e.,

```
ssh -fN -p 22 usr1@gate1 -L 10001:ip1:22
ssh -fN -p 22 usr2@gate2 -L 10002:ip2:22
...
ssh -fN -p 22 usrn@gaten -L 1000n:ipn:22
```

I can open the tunnels in background, which allows me to run them all together and then just type consecutively the password as many times as the number of tunnels I am opening (`n`).

Given that what I type is the same, I would like to find a way to type it just once, but still do it in a secure way.

Comment: use password less ogin with key, then have a look at `ssh-agent`. **or** use `sshpass`

Comment: Set up public/private key based login.

Comment: @Archemar I want to put the password explicitly, but only once. You are instead suggesting to install the keys and login without password right?

Comment: sshpass will help you, but password will appear in ps -ef result. password can be set to *keys* but you must allow for login without password. That why I reply as comment, I see no way you can do that, but maybe someone will be more clever than me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using https://stackoverflow.com/a/3980904/1424395 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59632/269821

I use `read -s` to get the password into a variable, and then I use `sshpass` to pass the password to the `ssh`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Read Password
echo -n Password:
read -s password
echo

sshpass -p $password ssh -fN -p 22 usr1@gate1 -L 10001:ip1:22
sshpass -p $password ssh -fN -p 22 usr2@gate2 -L 10002:ip2:22
...
sshpass -p $password ssh -fN -p 22 usrn@gaten -L 1000n:ipn:22
```