# create a user via script

Tags: bash, shell-script, here-document

I want to create a new user in a specific group when I issue the below command.

```
sudo ./create_user.sh "test" "firstname lastname"
```

The `create_user.sh` script looks as below.

```
#!bin/bash
#sudo adduser --gecos "$2" --ingroup testgroup $1
```

However, the problem is, I have to avoid the password insertion (it should be simply test) with a here document, but I have no idea about the syntax.

I tried some solutions but none of them seemed to work.

This is how my Try to of the heredocument in the script looks like

```
#<< EOF
#test
#test
#EOF
```

my output looks like this

```
#adding user 'test' ...
#adding new user 'test' <1003> with group 'testgroup' ...
#Enter new UNIX password:
```

Comment: Can you not pass the -p flag in the script to the adduser command if you're going to pass the password in the script anyway?

Comment: unfortunately not... its about learning the here document, i have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`adduser` calls the `passwd` utility to set a password. Like many programs that prompt for a password, `passwd` insists that its output comes from a terminal. So you cannot pass it input via a here-document — that creates a temporary file or a pipe, and `passwd` accepts neither.

You can pas `adduser` (at least the Debian version) the `--disabled-password` option if you don't want to be able to log in with a password (you'll still be able to log in with other methods such as SSH keys if you set them up). `adduser` doesn't have an option to pass the password hash (not the password itself), but `useradd` from the Linux shadow password utility suite does.

If you want to enter a password during the account creation, make sure that `passwd` reads from the terminal. If you obtain the password from some other source (e.g. a web form), call `passwd` from an [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) script — [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31071/shell-script-for-logging-into-a-ssh-server/31080#31080).

If this is an exercise in using a here document, the password is not where you should use it. I don't see any problem that a here document would solve in what you've posted.