# How to change password of an ssh identity file

Tags: ssh, password, ssh-keygen

Can I, and in that case how can I, change the password of an SSH identity file without having to generate a new key and setting up it all over again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change my private key passphrase?](https://serverfault.com/questions/50775/how-do-i-change-my-private-key-passphrase)

Comment: Yes, it does look like it is. Is there any policy about duplicates spanning different sub forums in the stackexchange network?

Comment: No, I don't think there is. I just added that link manually for the benefit of anybody searching here for a question similar to yours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell Script for logging into a ssh server](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31071/shell-script-for-logging-into-a-ssh-server)

Comment: @Invoker that's not a duplicate. This question is about changing the password for an existing key. The dupe you proposed is completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity file = private key file? From the manual, (`man ssh-keygen`):

> ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]

The `-p` switch changes the passphrase of a private key file with a prompt, whereas the `-P` switch specifies the old password on the command line. Use one of these in interactive mode depending on the encryption algorithm and file name you have used.

```
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```