# Auto login to SSH without keys?

Tags: ssh

I am looking for a way to ssh to a machine, without using SSH keys. When I try to pass the password

```
    echo "password" | ssh user@machine
```

It just gives me an stdin error

How do I SSH without using keys (and without installing anything would be preferred)

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31071/117549

Comment: or you can use `expect` as it may have been installed on your system already. If not, you can get information about how to install and use it from this page: http://expect.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Is not a good practice to login with on-line password.

I know you're asking a way to do this without installing something is preferred, but what I use is `sshpass` package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

Then execute the following

```
$ sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' ssh user@machine
```

Give a try.