# Pass password to a script running over ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, password

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31071/5116). I log into a remote server using ssh with a key pair (no password needed). On the remote server, there's a script of mine needing a password for something else.

When I log in and execute the script, I get prompted, enter the password and everything is fine:

```
my-local> ssh my-remote
my-remote> ./my-script
Password for something else: ***
OK
my-remote> exit
```

When I try to do it in a single step, I get an error like

```
my-local> ssh my-remote ./my-script
fatal: could not read Password for .... No such device or address
```

I wouldn't really mind entering the password, *if I only could.*

However, as a side question, I'd like to know if it's possible to pass the PW from "my-local" in a secure way (I don't want to store it in the script on "my-remote").

Both servers are Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool is reading from `tty` and if you specify a command to the `ssh`, it does not allocate you a TTY on the remote server and therefore it will fail. You can force `ssh` to allocate you TTY on the remote server using `-t` switch.

```
ssh -t my-remote ./my-script
```

should do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

Certain programs read directly from /dev/tty, not stdin. "passwd" for example.  So it's difficult to script them.  Expect is one way around that - it can trick the program by providing input to them:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236699/script-to-change-password-on-linux-servers-over-ssh

It can also help with the requirement to not have the passwords stored in a script or config file on each server - they would all be stored on the central machine, which you would guard closely of course...

Comment: I guess, the program reads from `/dev/tty/`, but I somehow though, `ssh` could forward my TTY. It should be possible, when `except` can do it. I'll look into it.