# SSH with password containing parenthesis

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to SSH to a server using a username whose password is: `Pa55w0rd12#45^78(`

The command i tried are:

```
[manu@xxx ]$ ssh manu:Pa55w0rd12#45^78(@xxxxxxx
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('


[manu@xxx ]$ ssh manu:"Pa55w0rd12#45^78("@xxxx
Password:
```

I have to follow the same command as this is in-product code and cannot be changed:

```
ssh username:password@server
```

Can anyone please direct me to a solution?

Comment: Quoting the parenthesis like you did is the way to have the shell pass it on as-is. Are you sure the password is supposed to go there with the username? And not where the SSH client prompts for a password..?

Comment: Read `man ssh`. That's not a valid way of specifying a password to `ssh`. Also read `man ssh-copy-id`.

Answer (score 4):

The ssh client that comes with OpenSSH does not support the syntax you quoted, where the password is provided in the command line.

If you are using a different ssh client, please let us know.

You should look into using keys for passwords-less logins, but if you really must, take a look at "sshpass" or "expect".

https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password

[Shell Script for logging into a ssh server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31071/shell-script-for-logging-into-a-ssh-server)