# Prompt for ssh password if needed, then pipe into the ssh session

Tags: ssh, pipe, stdin

As an experiment, I'm trying to write a script where I pipe a ZIP file into `unzip` on my server via `ssh`, however, what if I didn't have my SSH keys set up, and was prompted for a password? I'd still like it to come from `stdin`, not from the ZIP file - THEN I want to pipe a ZIP file into `unzip`, once the connection is established (maybe using two separate input pipes, one for the SSH password, one for the `unzip` process that `ssh` runs?).

Also, I'm currently writing into `/tmp` on the server, then deleting, because `unzip` doesn't seem to like `/dev/stdin` on my server (I'm running Arch, the server is running Ubuntu 20.04). `/dev/stdin` works when I pipe inside of the `ssh` session, it works when I pipe on my machine, but not when I pipe FROM my machine, into `ssh`. Any reason why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell Script for logging into a ssh server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31071/shell-script-for-logging-into-a-ssh-server)

Comment: SSH password prompt will avoid pipes by default - that is why if you *want* to pipe a password into the `ssh` command, you will need to take special steps as described in the question linked in Archemar's comment.

Comment: As @telcoM said, ssh password is **not** read from a pipe; but you can use the `sshpass` utility to automate entering password for ssh. So it will probably work if you use `sshpass` to provide password and pipe for the zip file.

Comment: Or you can install PuTTY for Linux; it contains the `plink` command that can be used as a replacement for `ssh` and it accepts password as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two unrelated problems.

1. How to programatically provide password into `ssh`.

As already noted in the comments, `ssh` does **not** read password from stdin (pipe); it reads it **directly from terminal**. So you cannot provide password to `ssh` via a pipe, but you can do it using the `sshpass` tool (you have to install it), like this:

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@host
```

Or you can read the password from a file, instead of providing it directly on the command line:

```
sshpass -f passwordfile.txt ssh user@host
```

You can also probably (I haven't tested this) use the `plink` command that is a part of [PuTTY for Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/1/plink) instead of `ssh`. `plink` accepts password as a parameter:

```
plink -pw 'password' user@host
```

2. `unzip` not accepting input from stdin.

According to text displayed by `unzip -hh`, `unzip` simply doesn't support reading the zipfile from stdin. If you want to unzip a file that you provide via stdin, you should use the `funzip` utility, like this:

```
cat file.zip | funzip >file.out
```

or

```
funzip <file.zip >file.out
```

However, be aware that `funzip` extracts only the first file from a zipfile.

So combining these two, you will have to use the following command:

```
cat file.zip | sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@host "funzip >file.out"
```

or

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@host "funzip >file.out" <file.zip
```

Enclosing the command `funzip >file.out` in quotes causes the file `file.out` to be created on the **remote** computer, not on your local one (if you omit the quotes, the file will be created on your local machine).